# Javascript simple animation lagging on mobile

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use a typing effect using 'setInterval', it works fine but lagging on mobile devices. I've slowed it down but still it lags, below I've attached the representation of what happening, also my code.

code:

```
function animate() {
  var a = "We DESIGN,";
  var b = "We DEVELOP";
  var c = "and";
  var d = "We CARE";
  var e = 0;

  var one = setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById('one').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',a[e]);
    e = e + 1;
    if (e == 10) {
      clearInterval(one);
      var f = 0;
      var two = setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementById('two').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',b[f]);
        f = f + 1;
        if (f == 10) {
          clearInterval(two);
          var g = 0;
          var three = setInterval(function () {
            document.getElementById('three').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',c[g]);
            g = g + 1;
            if (g == 3) {
              clearInterval(three);
              var h = 0;
              var four = setInterval(function () {
                document.getElementById('four').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',d[h]);
                h = h + 1;
                if (h == 7) {
                  clearInterval(four);
                }
              },200);
            }
          },150);
        }
      },200);
    }
  },200);
}
```

at first i used jquery's .append() but then tried pure js to see if it is doing anything, but no luck, and i'm calling this function onload() on body.
 Anyway, I've not really looked into the code to make it much smaller, so unless it isn't the reason please don't judge it.

on desktop: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Rv4bNu1X0wcHgbehYUb5WqzcVlA2gHTV

on mobile: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z8hCT71Xr_X9n3StDGRdn4TpLbx5TeQk

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById` is expensive. It traverses the DOM to find your element again and again for every character in the string. It makes more sense to store these elements in variables (better yet, use one container for the entire text block).

I'm not sure if setting and clearing intervals is more or less performant than the one-shot `setTimeout`, but I don't think there's any harm in making the switch, if only for cleanliness. I'm also using a promise for the same reason, but you can use a callback as easily if there's any trouble with making it async.

Beyond that, the code is difficult to maintain. If you want to add more text, the pyramid of doom grows and the code generally needs to be re-written. Use a loop.

I'd approach it as follows:

```js
const text = `We DESIGN,
We DEVELOP
and
We CARE`;
const typeElem = document.querySelector("#typewriter");

(async () => {
  for (const line of text.split("\n")) {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    typeElem.appendChild(div);

    for (const char of [...line]) {
      div.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", char);
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200));
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<div id="typewriter"></div>
```

Adjust timeouts to your specification (you could pause after a line, keep pauses per line/character in a separate data structure, etc).

Comment: thanks @ggurlen
i wrote this with what I know so far, will check your code and will try to understand what is happening

Comment: while i'm still understanding it, just wanted to let you know it didn't solve the issue of lagging on mobile.

Comment: Sorry to hear--I don't see any reason why this shouldn't run quickly on any machine. For that matter, even though your original code has a minor inefficiency or two, it shouldn't really matter. So, likely, the problem is elsewhere. Can you post enough of the rest of the code to reproduce the problem? One thing you could try is running the example code on this page on both devices. If the problem occurs, then you can be pretty sure this code is at fault. If not, then the problem is likely elsewhere.

Comment: so as you suggested I created a new page, only with this piece of code, and ran smoothly. So apparently yes, the problem is elsewhere. 
So, I started adding component one by one and testing it, to find out where it went all wrong. You see, I'm using media query for responsive design and thats why I've that viewport meta on my 'head' and apparently it started lagging right after I added this meta, made the page responsive.
code:

HTML - https://pastebin.com/pPbTdEhb

CSS - https://pastebin.com/grdPcXkX

Javscript - https://pastebin.com/dvZwfmPC

Comment: Interesting--nice debugging work. I recommend opening a new question with that code.